# why module not found error in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting error in `module not found error` I already install that module .

[image]

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bup8gb

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { DataService } from './dataservice';   // our custom service, see below
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ,HttpClientModule],
      providers: [DataService],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What version of angular do you have?

Comment: angular 5 version

Comment: Did you update recently? Try removing `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: actually I am using online editor see above link

Comment: Is your error just on stackblitz, or in your actual project. I've seen stackblitz's editor 'bug' sometimes, specifically with httpClient. The editor displays an error, but the code executes fine

Comment: stackblitz ..ok I am using `stackblitz`

Comment: I think this might be a bug in stackblitz